# Changes in GUI behavior after update

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, launcher, software-updater

[Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit, Unity 5.18.0]
On Friday morning I installed the recommended software updates, as I always do (list included at the end of this message). The next day, after rebooting, the GUI evinced some changes in behavior as follows:

- Launcher icons reverted to larger size (48x48?). And I can't shrink
  them back, because the icon size slider bar in the System Settings
  Appearance pane is gone.
- Hitting ctrl-alt-{arrow key} to switch
  workspaces no longer animates the process; the transition is
  instantaneous.
- Holding down the Super key no longer brings up the
  pane of all the keyboard shortcuts; it brings up the shortcut numbers
  over the launcher icons, and stops there.
- Hitting Super-W no longer
  does that Mac OS X Exposé-style "show all windows" trick.
- The alt-tab
  behavior for switching windows is much less flashy now. The row of
  icons is much smaller. It shows one icon per window, instead of one
  per application. Pausing over an app icon used to make it expand into
  all the windows the app had open; that behavior is gone. While alt is
  held down, it does show a white outline of whatever window is
  selected.

None of this is important. But it seems that some or all of these differences resulted directly from the software updates, so I'm curious & in general would like to improve my understanding of what these packages do.

Thanks in advance. Friday's updates are listed below, as promised.

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep -i status\ installed
2013-03-01 11:26:56 status installed libssl1.0.0 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.7
2013-03-01 11:26:57 status installed libc-bin 2.15-0ubuntu10.3
2013-03-01 11:27:42 status installed man-db 2.6.1-2ubuntu1
2013-03-01 11:27:42 status installed ureadahead 0.100.0-12
2013-03-01 11:27:43 status installed bamfdaemon 0.2.124.2-0ubuntu1
2013-03-01 11:27:43 status installed desktop-file-utils 0.20-0ubuntu3
2013-03-01 11:27:43 status installed gnome-menus 3.4.0-0ubuntu1
2013-03-01 11:27:45 status installed libdbus-glib-1-2 0.98-1ubuntu1.1
2013-03-01 11:27:45 status installed libgl1-mesa-dri 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.4
2013-03-01 11:27:46 status installed libglapi-mesa 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.4
2013-03-01 11:27:46 status installed libgl1-mesa-glx 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.4
2013-03-01 11:27:47 status installed libxatracker1 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.4
2013-03-01 11:27:47 status installed libglu1-mesa 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.4
2013-03-01 11:27:48 status installed sudo 1.8.3p1-1ubuntu3.4
2013-03-01 11:27:48 status installed openssl 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.7
2013-03-01 11:27:49 status installed firefox 19.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
2013-03-01 11:27:50 status installed firefox-globalmenu 19.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
2013-03-01 11:27:50 status installed firefox-gnome-support 19.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
2013-03-01 11:27:50 status installed firefox-locale-en 19.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
2013-03-01 11:27:51 status installed xserver-xorg-video-nouveau 1:0.0.16+git20111201+b5534a1-1build3
2013-03-01 11:27:51 status installed libc-bin 2.15-0ubuntu10.3
```

Comment: None of the packages in your list have to do with Unity at all. `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` and all the `mesa`libraries that you have are related to graphics drivers, nouveau specifically being about nvidia so an update of those packages probably broke something in that regard, if you can use Synaptic to rollback those packages to the previous version.

Comment: if there was an error with your video drivers because of the update, you may have defaulted to unity 2D which doesn't have the launcher icon resize capabilities, nor many of the other keyboard tricks you mention.

Comment: @UriHerrera - I was using the nvidia drivers before... how can I tell whether the nvidia or the nouveau are the ones being used? Can I delete the nouveau? Also, the `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` says 3D is not supported... but it might have been different before the update.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you lost the drivers to your graphics card during the update.  If you open "Software Sources" there should be a "Additional Drivers" tab where you can install drivers for your card.  If it doesn't list any drivers you'll have to do it manually.

Comment: OK I think I figured it out. My system does not officially support Unity 3D. Somehow I was able to install the Nvidia 302.07 drivers and 3D was working. Then the update broke that. I could probably keep 3D going by reinstalling the 302.07 drivers every time something went awry, but I'm not that invested in 3D, so I fired up Additional Drivers and installed the 295.40 drivers and am fine with 2D. Thank you all!!